# Summation of a finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Let

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+...+ \frac{1}{2^n-1} \forall \ n \ \epsilon \ \mathbb{N} $$

If it cannot be summed , are there any approximations to the series ?

Comment: In which contest was it asked? Are you that it is *contest* question?

Answer (score 3):

$$f(n)\approx \ln(2^n-1)+\gamma\approx n\ln 2+\gamma$$

Answer (score 2):

$$1+(\frac12+\frac12)+ (\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14)+ \dots (\dots \frac1{2^{n-1}})\gt$$

$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}+...+ \frac{1}{2^n-1}\gt$$  $$1+\frac12+(\frac14+\frac14)+(\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18)+\dots +( \dots \frac1{2^n})$$ (compare equivalent terms, and count the elements in the last bracket carefully) gives some bounds (the summation is straightforward). Since $\frac 1n$ is monotone decreasing, it is easy to use the integral to give tighter bounds than this.

The question is tagged as a contest, so integration may not be appropriate (depends on contest parameters). On the other hand the sums above, though rather crude, can be computed in a contest, and make sense of the relationship of the sum with a power of $2$.

I'd be interested in a better elementary estimate not involving integration.

Answer (score 1):

$f(n)=H_{2^n-1}$, the $(2^n-1)$-st [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). There is no closed form, but link gives the excellent approximation

$$H_n\approx\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{B_{2k}}{2kn^{2k}}=\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}-\ldots\;,$$

where $\gamma\approx 0.5772156649$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and the $B_{2k}$ are [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers).